# GtkWindow is not loading widgets

Tags: c, widget, gtk

I am playing with gtk4 and have the following

```
static void startapp(GtkApplication *app)
{
    GtkWindow *window = (GtkWindow*)gtk_window_new();
    gtk_window_set_application(window, app);
    gtk_window_set_titlebar(window, gtk_header_bar_new());
    gtk_header_bar_set_show_title_buttons(
        (GtkHeaderBar*)gtk_window_get_titlebar(window), TRUE);
    gtk_window_set_default_widget(window, gtk_button_new_with_label("bar"));
    gtk_window_present(window);
}

int main (int response, char **name)
{
  GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new ("org.foo", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect(app, "activate", (GCallback)startapp, NULL);
  response = g_application_run((GApplication*)app, response, name);
  g_object_unref(app);
  return response;
}
```

### What works

- The program starts
- The window can set widget via title bar

### What isn't

- The program is not showing the button widget inside the window

I dont think it has something to do with the `int response` variable. I did create another variable inside the code body and replaced `response = ... ; return response` with `int foo = ...; return foo`

So why isn't the window loading widgets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GTK4, you want `gtk_window_set_child` to set a child of a window (like GTK3, only one child is allowed).

So you want `gtk_window_set_child(window, gtk_button_new_with_label("bar"));` instead of the line `gtk_window_set_default_widget(window, gtk_button_new_with_label("bar"));`

Comment: shoot, i was using `set_default_widget` ... silly me